# Find the density of a function of a random variable with known distribution

Tags: probability, density-function

For example, if $X$ is a normal r.v than the distribution of $Z=X^{2}$ is (F is the CDF):
$$F_{Z}(z)=P(Z<z)=P(X^{2}<z)=P(-\sqrt{z}<X<\sqrt{z})=F_{X}(\sqrt{z})-F_{X}(-\sqrt{z}) −P(X=\sqrt{z})$$
This one's easy, but what if  $Z= X^{X}$, we'll have : $F_{Z}(z)=P(Z<z)=P(X^{X}<z)$. How do I proceed from here? or is there another way to determine the distribution of $Z$?

EDIT: Suppose that X is drawn from a Binomial distribution

Comment: If $X$ has a $N(0,1)$ distribution, then $X^X$ has the Shields distribution (as it shall be henceforth be known)

Comment: @MarkL.Stone: $X^X$ has a problematic distribution if $X$ can take arbitrary negative real values

Comment: In fact $P(X^{2}<z)=P(-\sqrt{z} < X<\sqrt{z}) = F_X(\sqrt{z}) - F_X(-\sqrt{z}) -P(X=\sqrt{z})$.  You need to be aware that $x^x$ is a strictly monotonic bijective function for $x \ge 1$ but not for $x \ge 0$, and is complicated (usually complex) for $x < 0$

Comment: @Henry, isn't there any other way to determine the distribution? initially I started to calculate the characteristic, but I needed the distributon of x^x to complete the calculations.

Comment: If $X$ has a Binomial distribution, that makes the problem trivial.  By definition a Binomial distribution has a certain chance of producing a $0$, a chance of a $1$, *etc*, through a maximum integral value $n$.  It therefore has *exactly the same chances* of producing $0^0=1$, $1^1=1$, $2^2=4$, all the way through $n^n$. The chances of the first two add, because they correspond to the same outcome ($X^X=1$), but otherwise all the other outcomes are still distinct. That is such a departure from the original example of a Normal distribution, it makes me wonder whether it's what you want to ask.

Comment: @whuber: I see, is it possible to determine the exact formula of it's distribution?

Comment: Yes: use the fact that the probability that $X=k$ for a Binomial$(n,p)$ distribution is $\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$.

Comment: @whuber: so the distribution of Z is a binomial, except for when Z=0 or 1, then its distribution is the sum of probabilities when X=0 and X=1?

Comment: A Binomial$(n,p)$ distribution assigns positive probability to every integer from $0$ through $n$. Your distribution assigns positive probability only to the integers $1, 2^2, 3^3,$ through $n^n$. In particular, your distribution assigns *zero* probability to $0$ (because $X^X$ can never equal $0$), proving right there that it is not Binomial. The point is that a distribution isn't just a bunch of numbers, nor is it a bunch of probabilities: it is a way to tell us how to assign probabilities to sets of numbers. Although you have Binomial *probabilities*, they are assigned to non-Binomial sets.